# Developing the same .NET Core source code as both .NET Core 1 and .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've run into a rather interesting problem at work. We have a .NET Core application that we need to develop. Because it's spent so long in development, it's all written in .NET Core version 1.

Now we add support for Microsoft OpenID to it. The thing is, Microsoft OpenID doesn't work with .NET Core version 1, it needs .NET Core version 3.

At the same time, customers are expecting steady deliveries, so we can't risk breaking the old .NET Core version 1 application until we have a fully working version of it written in .NET Core version 3.

So what I did was to make a different project in the same source code folder, using .NET Core version 3, and add the exact same source code files to it. Not duplicates - the exact same files. I just needed to add a bunch of #if - #endif directives to get around differences between versions 1 and 3.

But then there's the thing that the .NET Core version 1 application needs a global.json file containing "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121" in the "sdk" section, otherwise Visual Studio will try to compile it in .NET Core version 3, which will fail. This, however, will break the new version, which needs to use sdk version "3.1.300".

So in effect I would need to have two different "version" lines in the same "sdk" section in the same global.json file, with some kind of #if - #endif directive for conditional compilation. But I don't think global.json supports that.

How can I resolve this problem? Or is there any better way I haven't thought of?

Comment: You're using source control, right? You know how to do a branch?

Comment: The thing is, the whole reason I am using the same source code files instead of duplicates in the first place is that this way I only need to make changes to the source code once and it will automatically update both versions. If I were to use a branch I would have two separate copies of the source code so I would have to keep updating the copies, or otherwise one of them would fall out of date. Using the same source code does this automatically.

Comment: It's trivially easy to merge from one branch to another. You're using Git, right? The industry standard?

Comment: Microsoft TFS actually. We're planning on migrating to Git. But I suppose TFS also knows how to merge branches.

Comment: TFS itself is not source control, you're most likely using TFVC. TFS supports Git: you should migrate to it.

Comment: The way you're doing it, you just make your source code super messy. Really don't do it with `#if - #endif` directives everywhere. Do as suggested above, use `git`. Create a branch, do your migration to .NET Core 3.1 (the LTS version) and merge it to your `develop` branch. If there have been some commits while you were working on the migration just rebase

Comment: Can't you have two different global.json files, one for each project?

Comment: global.json files are directory-specific, not project-specific. And to be able to use the same source code files, the projects are in the same directory.